# netcore31 error with devexpress with winform

Tags: winforms, devexpress

```
public partial class FrmMain : RibbonForm
    {
        public FrmMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
```

```
dev20.1 
for net472  ok
for netcore3.1 error
```

> quote

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/641fJ.png)
*italic*

```
**
The type initializer for 'DevExpress.Utils.Helpers.IconGuard' threw an exception.

InnerException {"Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'field')"} System.Exception {System.ArgumentNullException}

   at DevExpress.Utils.Helpers.IconGuard.IsDisposedOrInvalid(Icon icon)
   at DevExpress.XtraEditors.FormIconOptions.FormIconHelper.GetIconHandleSafely(Icon icon)
   at DevExpress.XtraEditors.FormIconOptions.CheckUpdateIcon()
   at DevExpress.XtraEditors.FormIconOptions.get_Icon()
   at DevExpress.XtraEditors.FormIconOptions.get_UseIconImage()
   at DevExpress.XtraEditors.FormIconOptions.UpdateIcon(Boolean redrawFrame)
   at DevExpress.XtraEditors.FormIconOptions.InitializeIcon(Boolean redrawFrame)
   at DevExpress.XtraEditors.FormIconOptions..ctor(XtraForm form, Boolean initIconImmediately)
   at DevExpress.XtraEditors.FormIconOptions..ctor(XtraForm form)
   at DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm.CreateIconOptions()
   at DevExpress.XtraEditors.XtraForm..ctor()
   at DevExpress.XtraBars.Ribbon.RibbonForm..ctor()
   at SimpleWinForms_netcore.FrmMain..ctor() in D:\Tencent\FileRecv\SimpleWinForms_netcore-master\SimpleWinForms_netcore\FrmMain.cs:line 16
   at SimpleWinForms_netcore.Program.Main() in D:\\Tencent\FileRecv\SimpleWinForms_netcore-master\SimpleWinForms_netcore\Program.cs:line 28
**
```

```
https://github.com/h0730303779/SimpleWinForms_netcore-master/tree/master/SimpleWinForms_netcore
```

I'm worikng on a winforms application which uses DevExpress controls.

I user  verison dexpress 20.1.3.

the net471 is normal.

but netcore31 cannot run ? ?How can I use it normally>?

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [sources](https://github.com/h0730303779/SimpleWinForms_netcore-master/blob/master/SimpleWinForms_netcore/SimpleWinForms_netcore.csproj):

```
 <Reference Include="DevExpress.Data.v20.1">
   <HintPath>D:\开发软件\DevExpress 20.1\Components\Bin\Framework\DevExpress.Data.v20.1.dll</HintPath>
 </Reference>
```

It looks like you are using the same assemblies both for the .Net Core and Full Framework.
This is **incorrect**. For .Net Core, you should use assemblies built especially for .Net Core.

You can learn more at the [.NET Core Support](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/401191/dotnet-core-support) documentation article.